# Get Random value from Set python

Tags: python, random, set

I want to get a random value from a set. The following is my code which doesn't work.

I get the Error:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 320, in sample
>               raise ValueError("sample larger than population")
>       ValueError: sample larger than population

I don't have any idea what this means. I want to get an integer, so I can add this integer to a set. So I have `N` randomly chosen elements from one set put into another.

```
def getRandomBook():
    bookset = getBookSet()
    random_number = random.sample(bookset,1)
    print random_number[0]
    return_number = random_number[0]
    return return_number


def getBookSet(sales_input=open("data/sales_3yr.csv", "r")):
    sales = csv.reader(sales_input)
    bookID = set()
    lineNumber = 0    
    for line in sales:
        id = line[6]
        if lineNumber<>0:
            bookID.add(eval(id))
        lineNumber=1
    return bookID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your set is empty, and the set is empty because your `getBookSet()` function will read from a file object that has already been read from before.

You are opening the file as part of the function *definition*, which means you can only read it once. Do not use function default parameters for expressions you want to be evaluated each time the function is called. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Do this instead:

```
def getBookSet(sales_input="data/sales_3yr.csv"):
    sales = csv.reader(open(sales_input, 'rb'))
    bookID = set()
    lineNumber = 0    
    for line in sales:
        id = line[6]
        if lineNumber<>0:
            bookID.add(eval(id))
        lineNumber=1
    return bookID
```

Now the function opens the file object each time the function is called and starts reading from the first byte again. The `sales_input` parameter is now a immutable string, used to open the file object when running the function instead of when defining the function.

Correcting a few other issues:

```
def getBookSet(sales_input="data/sales_3yr.csv"):
    with open(sales_input, 'rb') as sales_file:
        sales = csv.reader(sales_file)
        next(sales, None)  # skip the first line
        return {int(row[6]) for row in sales}
```

- The `next()` call will pull in that first line for us (the headers) and any further looping over `sales` will continue from the next line.
- Don't use `<>`; it is deprecated. You could test for `if lineNumber` or `if lineNumber > 0` or `if lineNumber != 0` instead ( in order of preference).
- Don't use `eval()` when `int()` or `float()` will do just fine.
- Use `with` to close files automatically when done with the block of code.